# Is it possible to make ion view zoomable?

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to make a view in ionic zoomable when pinch. Is it possible to achieve this? I have see many many posts about zoom images and some of them work fine. But i want to make ion-view acts the same way and i haven't find any solution yet.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may add an `ion-scroll` inside your `ion-view` to enable zooming

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" style="width: 400px; height: 400px">
    <div>
      Your content goes here
    </div>
  </ion-scroll>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: I try it but does not work. This allow me to have scroll. I want to be able to zoom in the view like if i have an image